# Strange behaviour of two simple SQL Statement (Error) and one is crashing

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a database table with 50.000 customer data records.
When I run this query:

`SELECT * FROM customer`
--> The result is, that I get only 22.000 data records.

When I run this query:

`SELECT * FROM customer WHERE customer_id < 50.001`

--> The result is 50.000 data records

I did a CHECKTABLE, but there are no error messages.

Does anyone have an idea? Yesterday still everything was fine in the database and running. But today I have this issue.

Comment: What happens if you do a select count(*)? What tool are you using to do the sql? Can it have som limits on how many rows are returned? You dont write about what is crashing.

Comment: did you have any transaction oppened on the server? Restart it please and try it again...

Comment: It is not possible for a `where` clause to *increase* the number of rows in SQL Server.  There are many possible problems:  the queries are running on different databases; there is a `where` clause on the second query; your application is somehow filtering the rows; and so on.

Comment: I had similar problem in our DB, It was 2-3 year ago. I remember that trouble was with CHECK Constraints and we couldnt get right select

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I've edited your question to include the tag for your specific sql server version.

Comment: Sounds like there might be some sort of data corruption going on. Do you only get the first 22,000 records, or a random selection? Have you tried a `DBCC CHECKDB`? The `CHECKTABLE` may not be sufficient if, for example, the issue is with disk allocation.

Comment: Both queries run in the same query window or different ones? Is there a remote possibility that you ran `SET ROWCOUNT 22000` in the session which returns partial rows?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.
Finally the error was a broken INDEX on the primary key of that table. Now everything is fine again.